# How to show thousands grouping in a Swift calculator?

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I have code for my simple calculator.

How can I make the division of thousands so that when you enter numbers they are automatically separated by a dot?

For example:

Before:

> 1000000

After:

> 1.000.000

Code for calculator:

```
var stillTyping = false
var dotIsPlaced = false
var firstOperand: Double = 0
var secondOperand: Double = 0
var operationSign: String = ""
var currentInput: Double {
    get {
        return Double (displayResultLabel.text!)!
    }
    set {
        let value = "\(newValue)"
        let ValueArray = (value.components(separatedBy:"."))
        if ValueArray[1] == "0" {
            displayResultLabel.text = "\(ValueArray[0])"
        } else {
            displayResultLabel.text = "\(newValue)"
        }
        stillTyping = false
    }
}

@IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let number = sender.currentTitle!
    if stillTyping {
        if (displayResultLabel.text?.characters.count)! < 14 {
            displayResultLabel.text = displayResultLabel.text! + number
        }
    } else {
        displayResultLabel.text = number
        stillTyping = true
    }
}

@IBAction func twoOperandsSignPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    operationSign = sender.currentTitle!
    firstOperand = currentInput
    stillTyping = false
    dotIsPlaced = false
}

func operateWithTwoOperands(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    currentInput = operation(firstOperand, secondOperand)
    stillTyping = false
}
```

Comment: Do you always want to see `1.000.000`? Or do you only want that in locales for which that is common convention (e.g. Berlin, but not London)? We generally want to show it in the format specified by the device's `Locale` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this extension, which works with `NumberFormatter`:

```
struct Number {
    static let formatterWithDots: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.groupingSeparator = "." // only include this if you want to use dots regardless of the locale
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension Double {
    var formattedWithDots: String? {
        return Number.formatterWithDots.string(from: self as NSNumber)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textFieldDidChange), name: .UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc fileprivate func textFieldDidChange() {
    if let number = Double(textField.text ?? "") {
        textField.text = number.formattedWithDots
    }
}
```

Comment: I need that when the user enters a number (1000), then it would automatically be separated by a dot (1.000)

Comment: Check my edited answer. With a little tweaking to your needs, it should do the job.

Comment: For the display of numbers, I use Label- "displayResultLabel"

Comment: Do not set the formatter's grouping separator. Let the formatter format the number based on the user's locale. Some people want to see `1,000.0`. Some want to see `1.000,0`. Some want to see `1 000,0`, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy Sure, it can be true if an app is meant to be localized, I just assumed this is what the OP wants, because they mentioned that they want a dot as a separator.

Comment: @the4kman Most likely the OP lives where the `.` is used as the grouping separator and they are unaware that different locales use different grouping formatting.